# React. How to get access to state or props of already created component objects?

Tags: reactjs

I wish to create a component which will be used like this:

```
<OptionContainer>
  <Option value={value1} />
  <Option value={value2} />
  <Option value={value3} />
</OptionContainer>
```

Can I somehow get access to option value inside container component? The problem is that container receives options as children(as already created objects) and can't pass anything to props. Are there any solutions?

Comment: You shouldn't, this is one of React principles. The flow of data is from the parents to the children, making it unidirectional, you should never pass props from the children to the parent. However you can pass functions to the children that edit the data from the parent. I didin't fully understand your issue and reasoned that this was the problem, if your problem isn't the one mentioned tell me and i will edit my answer.

Comment: @Gabri, Usually we pass data and functions through props from parent to child and in this case we have to pass those data to parent's props. But in my case we pass value to <Option> component, so parent don't have those data. For more, parent receives already created objects instead of just receive data and create an option by himself.

Comment: Then the best way to deal with it is giving the state to the parent, and edit it inside the children, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should** abstract away the props passed to OptionContainer.

Its responsibility is to create the Option components, otherwise you're breaking the **single responsibility** rule, which may lead to lower code maintainability, harder to find and fix bugs, etc.

It also hinders the **reusability** of the OptionContainer, as you're forced to always pass the React-specific html instead of simple data, such as:

```
[
  { value: "option1" },
  { value: "option2" }
]
```

which makes creation of such props a whole lot harder.

If you were to receive an array of already created objects as a result of a backend response, then you’re really tying yourself to one technology (React in this scenario) and making the API calls not portable at all.

With that being said, I strongly suggest refactoring the OptionContainer's parent component to pass in props as an abstracted data set mentioned above, instead of framework-specific syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can access but as Gabri wrote I strongly discourage it. I have never needed this

```
const childrenData = React.Children.map(children, child => child.props)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the data of the children from the parent, a better approach would be giving the parent the data and pass it to the children along with a function to edit it.

```
const OptionContainer = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

return (
  <Option value={value} changeValue={setValue} />
);

}
```